# JPA/Hibernate query construction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I am fetching records from my "record" table. "record" table has many columns  tow of which are

1. client_id,  foreign key mapping to client table.
2. creation_date , date of record creation

I would like to do a query on this table , but I would like to fetch only one record per client(latest creation_date record has preference).

Will following work?

```
select r.id,r.xx,r.yy
group by(r.client_id),r.creation_date 
from record r 
order by creation_date desc
```

I tried above and seems records fetched are not of latest creation dates.
Hope my question is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a good starting point in HQL.

```
from Record as r inner join fetch r.client
where r.creation_date > (
    select max(rec.creation_date) from Record rec
    where rec.client.client_id = r.client.client_id
)
```

This of course assumes that your Record has a reference to its parent Client called `client`.

Comment: Doesn't `max(rec.creation_date)` get the max for the entire DB; not for the group?

Comment: @beerbajay Good catch... I fixed it so that for each record of `r` it will get the max creation date for `r` client_id.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep your query and add a `WHERE` condition :

```
SELECT r.id,r.xx,r.yy
GROUP BY(r.client_id)
FROM record r
WHERE r.creation_date = (SELECT MAX(creation_date) FROM record tmp WHERE tmp.client_id = r.client_id )
```

Take a look at [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)